# MongoDB connection to MongoLab timing out in NodeJS on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

At first everything works, and I can successfully store data by posting to the /upload route. But after 120 seconds of inactivity, the timeout event fires, and future attempts to store data fail. However the callback isn't called, so there is no `"Unable to insert..."` message at the log.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var winston = require('winston');
var config = require('./config');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  req.json({status: 'recieved'});
  req.app.locals.db.collection('data').insertOne(req.body, function(err, result) {
    if (err === null) {
      winston.info('Successfully inserted', {data: req.body});
    } else {
      winston.warn('Unable to insert', {cause: err});
    }
  });
});

const options = {
  server: {
    socketOptions: {
      keepAlive: 1,
      autoReconnect: true,
      connectTimeoutMS: 5000
    }
  }
};

MongoClient.connect(config.databaseURI, function(err, db) {
  if (err !== null) {
    winston.error('Could not connect to database', {cause: err});
    return;
  }

  db.on('timeout', function (err) {
    winston.error('Mongo timed out', {cause: err});
  });

  app.locals.db = db;
  app.listen(config.port, function() {
    winston.info('Listening on port %d', config.port);
  });
});
```

I based my code loosely off of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33122516/1078199). It has been suggested to me that I open a new connection to the DB after every request, but this [is not best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14464750/1078199) since internally, `MongoClient.connect` is managing a pool. I also tried changing some of the options according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418463/1078199). Still no luck.

Comment: Someone had a similar problem from a while ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670179/application-times-out-when-connecting-to-mongolab-from-heroku). Are you setting the node and npm engine values inside package.json?

Comment: I tried out the code he has, and heroku refuses to compile the app stating `Unable to download node 0.6.12; does it exist?` Unfortunately the author of that solution recommends downgrading node and npm, but doesn't explain why that fixes anything, so I am not sure which version to try next.

Answer (score 3):

This solved the problem for me:

```
var options = { 
  server: { 
    socketOptions: { 
      keepAlive: 300000, connectTimeoutMS: 30000 
    } 
  }, 
  replset: { 
    socketOptions: { 
      keepAlive: 300000, 
      connectTimeoutMS : 30000 
    } 
  } 
};
```

Then put it in here:

```
if(process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, options);
} else {

  // Connect to local database

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude. You save my day.

Comment: Awesomeness shaosh

Comment: See also [here](https://blog.mlab.com/2014/04/mongodb-driver-mongoose/#Production-ready_connection_settings)